# Junit Testing void 2D array

Tags: java, junit, multidimensional-array

I'm just starting out with testing.

The method I'm trying to test has no return value (void), but it creates a static 2D array (char[][]) in its own class, so from what I understand, that is its side effect.

Here is some mock code:

```
public class MyClass{

    public static char[][] table;

    public void setTable(int rows, int columns, int number){
        board = new char[n][m];
        // more code that alters the table in a specific way, 
        // depending on the 3rd parameter
    }
```

Now for the testing, I was thinking of doing something like:

```
public class SetTableTest{

    @Test
    public void test(){
        MyClass test = new MyClass();
        assertArrayEquals(**********, test.table);
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Am I allowed comparing to a static variable like I did (`test.table`) ie. will that actually return an "instance" of the completed table?
2. I'm fairly certain that there's no `assertArrayEquals` equivalent for 2D arrays, so how do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers:

1. Yes, the static variable will return the instance of the completed
   table, **assuming** that at the end of `setTable()` you set the
   completed table to the `table` variable. If you don't then it will not have the
   correct instance.

   However, from a design standpoint, it would be better to
   have an accessor method, such as `getTable()` for the completed table if you are setting
   it to a variable in `MyClass`, but that is a different issue.
2. To test that the 2D array is created, I would suggest creating an array that represents each row of the 2D array, example

   ```
   char[] row0 == test.table[0]
   char[] row1 == test.table[1].
   ```

   You would need to create these Arrays yourself filled with the values you would expect to be in the table created from `setTable()`. Then you can have use `assertArrayEquals()` for each row. Example:

   ```
   public class SetTableTest{

       @Test
       public void test(){
           MyClass test = new MyClass();
           test.setTable(2, 2, 5);
           char[] row0 = {x, x} // This is whatever you would expect to be in row 0
           char[] row1 = {x, x} // This is whatever you would expect to be in row 1
           assertArrayEquals(row0, test.table[0]);
           assertArrayEquals(row1, test.table[1]);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 7):

The answer is already given, but for the sake of other users I am going to add another approach.

To compare two arrays, `double[][] arr1, arr2`, one may use `Arrays.deepequals(arr1, arr2)` which returns `true` or `false`. The signature of this fucntion is:

```
java.util.Arrays.deepEquals(Object[] a1, Object[] a2)
```

For a unit test a single line would then suffice:

```
assertTrue(Arrays.deepEquals(arr1, arr2));
```

Comment: This works great. However one shortcoming is the fact that when the test fails you get `expected: <true> but was: <false>`, whereas the approach using arrayEquals provides  more detail on why the assertion failed: `array contents differ at index [...], expected: <expected> but was: <actual>`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `assertArrayEquals()` here http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html

so you can use static import for it:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;
```

It is, however, only "shallow" array equals, so you need to implement the logic itself. Also make sure, you call the `setTable()` before asserting. Here is something:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertArrayEquals;

public class SetTableTest{

    @Test
    public void test() {
        MyClass test = new MyClass();
        int foo = 42;
        int bar = 42;
        int baz = 42;
        test.setTable(foo, bar, baz)
        for (char[] innerArray : test.table) {
             assertArrayEquals(*****, innerArray);
        }
    }
}
```